# Web Deploy 3.5 Install Error - #2738

Tags: wordpress, dll, vbscript, windows-7-x64, webmatrix

I'm attempting to create a custom WordPress theme using MS WebMatrix and am encountering the following error when trying to install the WP app:

> Error 2738:  Could not access VBScript runtime for custom action

This occurs when the download attempts to install **Web Deploy 3.5**. I'm currently running Windows 7 64-bit OS.

The research that I've done indicates this is error stems from "VBScript being not properly configured to run on the PC."

The solutions I've encountered and tried - to no avail - are:

1. Run MS FixIT
2. Re-registering the VBScript dll via cmd prompt - `c:\windows\syswow64\regsvr32 vbscript.dll`
3. Run the System File Checker tool `sfc /scannow`

*[Note: I do not have, nor have I had McAfee installed - I've seen reports that in some instances the McAfee installation can cause the wrong vbscript .dll to be registered]*

Outside of doing a factory wipe - which I'd like to reserve as a last resort or completely scrap using WebMatrix entirely - I've run out of potential solutions searching this specific problem.

Has anyone had success with this issue outside of the solutions posted here already? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I discovered a solution to this issue that hasn't been covered well online, so I'm posting it here.

A steadfast solution to resolving this error if running Windows 7 64-bit OS:

- Open your registry editor

> Start -> Search -> Type "regedit"

- In the editor, click on:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\CLASSES\Wow6432Node\CLSID{B54F3741-5B07-11cf-A4B0-00AA004A55E8}\InprocServer32

- Check the value for `(Default)`
- If it's anything other than `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vbscript.dll` that's where your issue is originating
- Make sure you have the correct permissions to edit the value for `(default)`

> Right Click on InprocServer32 -> Permissions -> Give yourself "Full Control"

- Now edit `(Default)` and set it to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vbscript.dll`
- Reboot

This should fix any issues that might have been encountered during the execution of custom VBScript during Web Deploy download.